# How to enter to a particular date (link) within a calendar in selenium using java

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, calendar

I need to enter into the first day within a calendar which is a link.

**Note:** Only some of the days within the calendar are hyperlinks.

**What I do is:** I put all the days of the calendar into a list as a WebElements. Then, I go through the list and make a `break;` when I find a WebElement that contains a `href` I perform a click for that particular WebElement. See below:

```
for (WebElement e : listOfCalendarDays) {
    if (e.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("href="))
        if(!e.findElement(By.xpath(".//a")).getAttribute("href").isEmpty())) 
        {
            e.click();

        break;
    }                           
}
```

Please, somebody can tell me what I am doing wrong? I know that the list is fine because I did some tests that say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the `a` element containing `href` attribute:

```
driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("a[href]")).click();
```